# How i can use a function in sikuli which is defined in an another sikuliscript?

Tags: function, sikuli

I try to use `Sikuli`. I will have 2 Files. One of them will be the "main" file and one of then is for functions.

The main-file I have called "`test`" and the file for the Function I have called "`importi`".

If I run the main file, I will get the error:

> [error] Fehlermeldung: Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:...\Temp\sikuli-tmp8331266965127754273.py",line 3, in
>   importi.help()
>
> AttributeError: 'module'object has no attribute 'hallo'

This is my Code of the main-file:

```
import importi
importi.hallo()
```

and this is the code of the File with the function:

```
anzeige = "Hallo"
def help():
  popup(anzeige)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in the calling function you should write -

```
import importi
importi.help()
```

in above code "help" is the function name defined in called (or imported) function.
At the same time, below code should be saved as importi.sikuli file.

```
anzeige ="Hallo"
def help():
  popup(anzeige)
```

So, to summarize.
File ***importi.sikuli*** has -

```
anzeige ="Hallo"
def help():
  popup(anzeige)
```

And calling function (whatever name it has) is -

```
import importi
importi.help()
```